# Drawing a d3 realtime line chart inside socket.on (socket io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, d3.js

I am using values that I receive from a server via socket io, and I want to make a chart that updates in realtime, as new values arrive.

For drawing the graph I am using the code from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/YruDh/
And I receive the data in the form below:

```
 socket.on('news', function (data) { /*I make the chart here*/...});
```

I replaced the `value` field in the `next()` function by my own values, that is, the values I receive from the socket , and everything works great.

The only problem is that, everytime a new data point arrives, every two seconds, not only the graph gets updated, but I get an exact copy of the same chart in the browser, below the already existing graph. This continues to happen everytime I receive a new data point, until eventually I have 20 or more charts in my browser, causing it to crash at some point.

I tried to create the chart outside of `socket.on`, even using random data exactly as it is in the example above, and it doesn't show anything. So I assume that I need to create the graph and update it every two seconds in the socket.on() method.
How can I create and update the chart without making multiple copies of it?

Here is the full code I have now:

```
 socket.on('news', function (data) {

var o= JSON.parse(data);
awesome=o;
note3.push(awesome.valuee);
var t = -1
var n = 40,
    duration = 750
    data = d3.range(n).map(next);


   function next(){
    return {time: ++t, value: awesome.valuee }
    }

   var margin = {
    top: 6,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 40
    },
    width = 560 - margin.right,
    height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

     var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([t-n+1, t])
    .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.time.scale()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 400]);;

    var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d, i) {return x(d.time);})
    .y(function (d, i) {return y(d.value);});

   var svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height); 

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
   var axis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(x.axis=xAxis); */

   var path = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line");

   tick();

   function tick() {

    // update the domains
    x.domain([t - n + 2 , t]);

    // push the accumulated count onto the back, and reset the count
    data.push(next());

    // redraw the line
    svg.select(".line")
        .attr("d", line)
        .attr("transform", null);

    // slide the x-axis left
    axis.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(x.axis);

    // slide the line left
    path.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(t-n) + ")")
        .each("end", tick);

    // pop the old data point off the front
    data.shift();

}

});
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: In the code you reference the `tick` function is updating the chart.  Sounds like you are re-running the entire chart creation.  This is, of course, a guess because you haven't shown any of your code...  Create a reproducible example of your issue, otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: @Mark, I have edited the question with relevant code. Hope it helps you understand the issue.

Comment: Looking at your code confirms it, you are re-running the entire chart creation on each socket event.  You only need to run the `tick` function on each socket event.

Comment: @Mark that makes sense. However, if you look at the `next()` function, it uses the variable `awesome`, which is basically the data I receive from the server, and I can't use its value outside of the socket.on method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely untested code, but you need to restructure to something like this:

```
var t = -1,
  n = 40,
  duration = 750,
  data = [];

var margin = {
    top: 6,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 560 - margin.right,
  height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([t - n + 1, t])
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.time.scale()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, 400]);;

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return x(d.time);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("p").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var axis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(x.axis = xAxis); * /

var path = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
  .data([data])
  .attr("class", "line");

function tick() {

  // update the domains
  x.domain([t - n + 2, t]);

  // redraw the line
  svg.select(".line")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("transform", null);

  // slide the x-axis left
  axis.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease("linear")
    .call(x.axis);

  // slide the line left
  path.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(t - n) + ")");

  // pop the old data point off the front
  if (data.length > 40) data.shift();

}

socket.on('news', function(p) {

  p = JSON.parse(p);
  data.push({
    time: ++t,
    value: p.valuee
  })

  tick();

});
```

Comment: Hey Mark. It doesn't print anything, but I will try to see if I can make it work using this as base. Thank you.

Comment: More specifically, the variable `data` does not save any values. It is always empty.

Comment: The variable `data` has values while inside the socket.on method. But if we do `console.log` outside of that method, the same doesn't hold true. So the graphic doesn't form because it is outside of the method.

Comment: @manuelmourato, sorry, the `data.shift();` should not fire until you reach a certain number of points, see above.

Comment: thank you for your patience. I have tried the code with your modification to the data.shift() and it didn't work.
As I said yesterday, the problem here is that the `data` variable has the values I want inside function(p) in the socket.on() method, but not outside of it. So because we are creating the graph outside the socken.on method, the data variable is always empty, and the graph can't be drawn, no matter how long we wait for the data.shift.
Do you know anyway in which I can solve this?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Turns out you are absolutely right. I was making a silly mistake. It works perfectly. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**i have implemented this realtime plotting with D3 using ws websocket,you can check it out,this is the script,you will also have html here,but not added,moreover,there is a server,which serves this d3 file as well as generates random json,you can create this server and check if its realtime for time being**

```js
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
        </div>
            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <script>
                 var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/");
                var count = 0, tempArr = [];
                ws.onmessage = function (message) {
                    if(count<10) {
                        tempArr.push(JSON.parse(message.data));
                        count++;
                        
                    }
                    init();
                }
                    
                    function init(){
                        var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
                        WIDTH = 1000,
                        HEIGHT = 500,

                        MARGINS = {
                            top: 20,
                            right: 20,
                            bottom: 20,
                            left: 50
                        },
                        xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([2000, 2010]),
                        yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([134, 215]),
                        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(xScale),

                        yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(yScale)
                        .orient("left"); 
                    
                    vis.append("svg:g")
                        .attr("class", "x axis")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
                        .call(xAxis);
                    vis.append("svg:g")
                        .attr("class", "y axis")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
                        .call(yAxis);
                    

                    var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d) {
                            return xScale(d.year);
                        })
                        .y(function(d) {
                            return yScale(d.sale);
                        }) 
                        .interpolate("basis");
                    vis.append('svg:path')
                        //.enter()
                        .attr('d', lineGen(tempArr/*data*/))
                        //.attr('d', lineGen(obj.year))
                        .transition()
                        .duration(1000)
                        //.delay(2000)
                        .attr('stroke', 'green')
                        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
                        .attr('fill', 'none'); 
                        console.log(JSON.parse(message.data));
```