# How to save value from a function inside socket.on to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

This is probably very simple, but I am fairly new to programming in Javascript and using Socket IO.

When I want to give a global variable a value from inside a function the process is fairly simple:

```
var j;

function a(){
j=2;

}
a();
//j is now 2
```

My issue now is, I have a method called socket.on, which has a function inside it, like this:

```
var j;

socket.on('news', function (p) {
j=p; 
//in here, j is equal to p
});
//in here, j is NOT p, it is undefined.
```

Now, in this case I want my global variable j to have the value of p, but when I print j outside of the function, it is undefined. I assume this is because I need something like `a();` outside the function like in the first example. 
How can I do this in this case?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `socket.on` is a so called callback function, a very common pattern in javascript. In your example you are listening to the 'new' event. When this event occurs, the callback is fired with the argument `p`. Of course this argument is only available inside the callback function itself.

To be clear: You do **not** call the function in the second example directly. It is called once the 'news' event occurs.

The callback pattern is very handy, because it allows you to write non blocking code. While you are waiting for the 'news' event to occur, any code after your `socket.on` call is being executed normally. This is the reason why you cannot access `p` outside the callback: You don't know at what point in time the callback will be called.

I suppose you read a little more about Javascript's [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) or [functions and their scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that my goal for this code is to plot a graph with the data I receive from the callback function, with these `p` values. 
Now, in order to create and update the graph, I need these `p` values that keep coming. The problem is that if I draw the graph inside socket.on, I get a new copy of that graph each time I get a `p` value, which I do not want.
So my goal is to create the graph outside the socket.on method (it only creates the graph once), while updating the values from within socket.on.

Comment: I tried saving those `p` points to an array, which I declare outside of socket.on, but for the reasons you stated the array doesn't save any value that it receives to outside of the callback function. This is my issue.

Comment: You can refer to this link for the code in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697138/drawing-a-d3-realtime-line-chart-inside-socket-on-socket-io

Comment: It seams that your real problem has been solved in the other question, right? I there still anything unclear in this question that I can help with?

Comment: Yes, my doubt has been cleared, thank you very much for your help